# Changing value inside of array in local storage

Tags: javascript

So, I have an array stored in local storage called "users", with the fields "email", "id", "img", "pass", "user" and "usertype".

I want to have a field in which the user can change his email, but I can't do it. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
let loggedID = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("loggedID"))

changeEmailLink.addEventListener('click', function () {
    users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"))
    users[loggedID].email = document.getElementById('changeEmail').value

})
```

I think the only thing I'm missing is using "localstorage.setItem()" to apply the change, but I'm afraid I'll delete the user records I have stored already if I don't do it right.

Any help would be apreciated. Thanks!

P.S. I am sure the "loggedID" is working since I already used it multiple times on this project. Also no jquery please, only vanilla JS. :)

Comment: Yes, all you need to to is to assign to the `localStorage` property again

Comment: `but I'm afraid I'll delete the user records`  Don't be afraid, that's what testing is all about,..

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

```
changeEmailLink.addEventListener('click', function () {
    users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"))
    let usersUpd = users

    for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if (users[i].email == users[loggedID].email) {
            usersUpd[i].email = document.getElementById('changeEmail').value

        } else {

            usersUpd[i] = users[i]
        }
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(usersUpd))
    }

})
```

This is what I did and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use the `setItem` function to maintain the new state.

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
function setEmail(email) {
    let loggedID = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("loggedID"))
    let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"))
    let user = users[loggedID]
    user.email = email;
    localStorage.setItem("users", users)
}

changeEmailLink.addEventListener('click', function () {
    setEmail(document.getElementById('changeEmail').value)
})
```

Comment: It should write back all of the existing items in the array